# How to set an iframe url to redirect inside the iframe instead of redirecting to parent page

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

I have a WordPress page `https://www.sitename.com/manual`. In this page, I have an embedded HTML page.

`<iframe src="https://www.sitename/othermanual/aplication.htm"></iframe>`

What I am trying to do is take `aplication.htm` from the `src` in the `<iframe>` and make it part of 
`https://www.sitename.com/manual` 
to have something like this:

`https://www.sitename.com/manual?page=aplication.htm`

In summary, I am trying to parse the `aplication.htm` part of the url  and use it in the main url. I have read that it may be possible with anchors, are there any other approaches such as using JavaScript or AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things.

1. Put a `name="foo"` attribute on the iframe.
2. Put a `target="foo"` attribute on the anchor.  Then, when you click the link it will target the iframe instead of the whole page.

Edit:  I didn't properly understand the post so here is my updated solution.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    SetIframe();
});
```

This function will parse out *all* query-strings as key value pairs.  If you have any simple variables (variable but not value) then you'd need to tweak this but this should work for what you are doing.  Once you have the variable value, just load it into the `src` attribute and the iframe should load.  I put an id on the iframe to make it easier to target.

```
function SetIframe()
{
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    if (query.indexOf('page=') == -1)
        return;

    var vars = query.split('&');
    var kvp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++)
    {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');            
        if(pair.length == 2)
            kvp[pair[0]] = pair[1];            
    }
    console.log(kvp);

    if (typeof kvp['page'] != 'undefined')
        $('#myFrame').attr('src', kvp['page']);

}
```

Comment: I understand that but I want to do is be able to distribute the url and not target the parent page, I want to be able to send out the url  `https://www.sitename.com/manual?page=xxx.htm` with the url attributes of the embeded page.

Comment: Is `xxx.htm` the url for the iframe but `/manual` is the parent page?

Comment: Correct. `https://www.sitename.com/manual` is the page where I have the embedded page. This is the page that is embedded in the <iframe> `https://www.sitename/othermanual/xxx.htm` and I want to be able to do this `https://www.sitename.com/manual?page=xxx.htm` where this is directed in the main page  and  `?page=xxx.htm` is taken from the url of the page embedded.